# Есть ли язык программирования с GC, но в котором сложно восстановить исходный код?

Tags: любой-язык, сборщик-мусора

Ищу язык программирования с хорошим GC (не простой подсчёт ссылок, а на уровне java, например сборка по поколениям), но в котором сложно восстановить исходный код. Вот например в Go или Haskell не посмотришь исходный код, а в Java или C# он практически в открытом виде, почему так? Какие ещё языки поддерживают такое?

Comment: Возможность декомпилирования вообще никак не связана с наличием сборщика мусора. Если коротко и упрощенно, не декомпилируемые языки - те которые компилируются в нативный (машинный) код, декомпилируемые - компилируемые в байткод для виртуальной машины. GC в принципе может быть и в том и в другом случае.

Comment: с GC почти всегда обычно используется виртуальная машина в с помощью которой легко видеть исходный код. Только в go  и haskell это не посмотреть, а в Java и C# - легко, почему?

Comment: "Обычно" - это не правило, это ваше наблюдение. "Только в go и haskell это не посмотреть, а в Java и C# - легко, почему?" - потому что первые два компилируются в машинный код, вторые два - в код для VM, см мой комментарий выше. С GC это никак не связано.

Comment: ну приведите контр пример, есть язык с виртуальной машиной но без GC?

Comment: Навскидку не назову, но в принципе технически ничего не мешает создать такой язык (не понятно только зачем, потому что ручное управление памятью - это гемор).

Comment: а во вторых это МНЕ нужен GC

Comment: "а во вторых это МНЕ нужен GC" - вот это вообще не понятно к чему. Нужен - ну напишите или сделайте, или куда он вам там нужен.

Comment: Из практических соображений, могу только посоветовать посмотреть, например, на топ30 TIOBE и в табличке для себя (или даже в этом вопросе) расписать их стойкость к декомпиляции и наличие GC. Все что ниже, условно, 30ой позиции не рассматривать, т.к. такие языки проблематично использовать ввиду малой экосистемы.

Comment: В C# уже можно использовать Native AOT. Исходный код теперь никак не посмотришь.

Comment: "я суда пришёл совета спросить знающих людей, а вы мне что советуете - сделай сам? нормально вообще?" - а вы понятно задавайте вопросы, я не понимаю, что вообще означает "во вторых это МНЕ нужен GC". "нормально вообще?" - вообще - нормально, никто не обязан вам отвечать, типа "вынь да положь", и угадывать что на самом деле вам нужно.

Comment: Пишите на Racket! Я писал, да... Язык с GC. Декомпилировать можно, но... Много ли специалистов по нему? Сможет ли кто-то воспользоваться этим кодом?

Comment: _есть язык с виртуальной машиной но без GC?_ - C++ c LLVM :) Или любой другой язык для LLVM.

Comment: "Только в go и haskell это не посмотреть, а в Java и C# - легко, почему?" - вот вам другой ответ: в виртуальные машины JVM и .NET изначально вшит GC, поэтому фактически все языки, работающие поверх этих машин имеют GC. А для языков с компиляцией в нативный код GC нужно отдельно реализовывать.

Comment: Хотите усложнить декомпилирование байт-кода, возьмите функциональный язык. Например, F# для .NET, Scala для JVM. Там обычно выдаётся гораздо более запутанный код, по сравнению с C# и Java.

Comment: Т.е. в принципе вы путаете причину и следствия. Сложность декомпиляции - это не следствие того, что в языке есть GC, а наоборот, GC в языках с виртуальными машинами есть вследствие того, что в GC изначально встроен в сами виртуальные машины. Получается есть причина - наличие или отсутствие ВМ, а есть два следствия: легкость или сложность декомпиляции, легкость или сложность добавления в язык GC. Напрямую эти два следствия не связаны, хотя и кореллируют.

Answer (score 1):

Ну например эти? ><

- [BASIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BASIC)
- [LOGO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logo_(programming_language))
- [LISP](https://%20https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_(programming_language))
- [D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D_(programming_language))

Comment: Ставлю лайк за упоминание Лого-черепашки.